# JAXB XML Unmarshaller

Tags: xml, jaxb, resteasy, xml-namespaces, jaxb2

I am using JAXB and RestEasy.

I am returning a Comprobante.class (JAXB generated class) from a xml file that needs to have:

```
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd">...</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

I have this at package declaration:

```
@XmlSchema(
    location = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd",
    namespace = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    attributeFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED,

    xmlns={
        @XmlNs(
                prefix="cfdi",
                namespaceURI="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"
                ),
        @XmlNs(
                prefix="xsi",
                namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                )
        })
```

But the result of the unmarshaling from the XML file to the JAXB class doesn't have the:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd"
```

It only prints

```
<cfdi:Comprobante 
xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">..</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

My code is:

```
File p = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/")+factura.getXml().getCfdi());

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("foo.bar.Model.CFDIv32");
Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();

return (foo.bar.Comprobante) u.unmarshal(p);
```

How can i tell to JAXB Unmarshaller to put the xsi:schemaLocation="" property.

Thank you.

### EDIT: how i solved it

See my own answer

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer instead of an edit to your question?  This will be most helpful to people who are searching for the same problem you had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rest easy has JAXB Decorators, so you can add to marshaller properties before marshalling.

1.- Create a DecoratorProcessor

```
@DecorateTypes({"application/xml"})
public class NameSpaceProcesor implements DecoratorProcessor<Marshaller, CustomMarshaller> {

/* Override method</br>
 * @see org.jboss.resteasy.spi.interception.DecoratorProcessor#decorate(java.lang.Object, java.lang.annotation.Annotation, java.lang.Class, java.lang.annotation.Annotation[], javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType)
 */
@Override
public Marshaller decorate(Marshaller target, CustomMarshaller arg1,
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class arg2, Annotation[] arg3, MediaType arg4) {
    try {
        target.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        target.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION,"http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd");
    } catch (PropertyException e) {
    }
    return target;
}
}
```

2.- Create your Decorated Annotation.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Decorator(processor = NameSpaceProcesor.class, target = Marshaller.class)
public @interface CustomMarshaller {}
```

3.- Then annotate your method with the decorator.

```
    @GET
@CustomMarshaller
@Path("cfdi")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
// /consulta/cfdi?uuid=0a7da89b-a328-4e54-9666-e1a3d7a10b0a
public Comprobante cfdi(...){}
```

Hope this help some one else.